# How do I erase all the data on Galaxy S4 if the screen is broken?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, broken-screen, remote-wipe

I have Samsung Galaxy S4, but the screen broke. I wanted to erase all the data on it before I send it back to the factory for replacement. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please add detail to your question that way it help to get correct answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you ever registered a gmail address on your google play account(which you have to, to download apps), your phone will be registered in Google's Device Manager on play.google.com.  If your phone was connected to WiFi or Data when the screen broke the below method can work(I've tested it myself multiple times).

1. Head to play.google.com(From your PC)
2. Log in to your google account.
3. Click the 'gear' symbol in the top right hand corner of the screen.
4. Go To 'Android Device Manager'
5. Select your GS4 from the menu of your registered devices.
6. Select 'Erase' from the list.

That should erase the phone.

Comment: Will this wipe out ONLY the data on my broken phone (its memory) and NOT my simm card and removable memory card?

Comment: I always take my removeable memory card out before I format a phone, so I would probably do that.  It won't mess with your sim card.

Comment: ok thats what i thought.  Leave the sim card installed tho right? i did sync with Google so this method should preserve all my data for the new phone then.

Comment: Yeah, leave the sim card in.

Comment: Thanks!!! I will let u know how it goes later. Can't be too careful with info security/privacy these days.... MUCH APPRECIATED!!!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up to say that the wipeout on the old phone was a success and the sim card was not affected at all.  I still have all the data/info intact and functional on my new phone. thanks NEW TO IT guy!!!

Comment: Glad I could help @bigaznguy

Answer (score 1):

IF the LCD is no longer working but you can still see the display I would recommend an OTG cable [Walmart](http://www.walmart.com/ip/StarTech-5-Micro-USB-to-USB-OTG-Host-Adapter-M-F/27420736)

If the LCD is not working refer to New-To-IT's post

Another method would be to boot it into download mode and flash a new system image on it.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the phone to a computer/laptop using the micro-usb or charger that came with the phone then reset the phone.